# Cambiar nombre de las leyendas en R

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2, ggplot

Tengo el siguiente Gráfico:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría expresar las leyendas en español, ejemplo Brazil como Brasil. Esto se puede hacer modificando el dataset pero creo que debe haber una forma más rápida en ggplot.
Mi script es el siguiente

```
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(panelr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
data <- read_excel("2021-FKRSU-Update-12-08-2021.xlsx")
View(data)
attach(data)

# Armar Panel
data_panel <- panel_data(data, id = code_ifs, wave = year)


# Ahora agrupamos por region y mundial
          avgregion <- data %>% 
                           group_by(year, region) %>% 
                            summarize(ka_avg = mean(ka, na.rm=TRUE), 
                                      kao_avg = mean(kao, na.rm=TRUE))

          avgworld <- data %>% 
                           group_by(year) %>% 
                            summarize(ka_avg = mean(ka, na.rm=TRUE),
                                      kao_avg = mean(kao, na.rm=TRUE))
          avgworld$region <- "world"
          
          paises <- data.frame(data$year, data$country, data$ka, data$kao)
          colnames(paises) <- c("year", "region", "ka_avg", "kao_avg")
          
          
# Armo el data set para plot
          dataset <- bind_rows(avgregion, avgworld, paises)
          
# Plot
          
   dataset %>% 
            ggplot(aes(x=year,y=ka_avg, group=region))+
            geom_line(colour="grey", alpha=.4)+
            geom_line(aes(x=year,y=ka_avg, color=region),
                      data = dataset %>% filter(grepl("Chile|Brazil|Peru|Colombia|Argentina|world|Latin America & Caribbean",
                                                      region)), size=1, show.legend = T)+
            geom_text(aes(x=year+.3,y=ka_avg, label=region),
                      data = dataset %>% filter(grepl("Chile|Brazil|Peru|Colombia|Argentina|world|Latin America & Caribbean",
                                                      region),year==2020))+
            theme_classic()+
            ggtitle("Control de capitales")+
            xlab("")+
            ylab("")+
            theme(axis.line.x.bottom=element_line(size=1, colour = "grey"),
                  axis.text.x=element_text(size=10),
                  axis.text.y = element_text(size=10),
                  axis.line.y.left = element_line(size=1, colour = "grey"),
                  legend.title = element_blank())
```

Comment: No conozco una función que lo haga, pero puedes crear un data frame en donde tengas información de los países en inglés y en español. Quizá conozcas la técnica del web scraping, con ello lo puedes hacer más rápido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La única forma que encuentro para hacer esto es utilizando la función **gsub** para cambiar el nombre de las regiones en inglés por español.

Luego cambio **geom_line()** las regiones del **filter()**

## Armo el data set para plot

```
      dataset <- bind_rows(avgregion, avgworld, paises)
      dataset$region <- gsub('Brazil', 'Brasil', dataset$region) 
      dataset$region <- gsub('Latin America & Caribbean', 'LAC', dataset$region)
      dataset$region <-   gsub("Peru", "Perú", dataset$region)
      dataset$region <-   gsub("world", "Global", dataset$region)
```

## Plot

```
dataset %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x=year,y=ka_avg, group=region))+
        geom_line(colour="grey", alpha=.4)+
        geom_line(aes(x=year,y=ka_avg, color=region),
                  data = dataset %>% filter(grepl("Chile|Brasil|Perú|Colombia|Argentina|Global|LAC",
                                                  region)), size=1, show.legend = T)+
        theme_classic()+
        ggtitle("")+
        xlab("")+
        ylab("")+
        theme(axis.line.x.bottom=element_line(size=1, colour = "grey"),
              axis.text.x=element_text(size=10),
              axis.text.y = element_text(size=10),
              axis.line.y.left = element_line(size=1, colour = "grey"),
              legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]